# Why does template work and templateUrl not in my route resolve loading directive?

Tags: angularjs

My Angular application needs to resolve data before the controller is loaded.  I am using the answer provided here by tasseKATT:

[Apply loading spinner during ui-router resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200909/apply-loading-spinner-during-ui-router-resolve)

Though I am curious as to why I can use "template" but not "templateUrl."

**Works:**

```
app.directive('resolveLoader', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div class="alert alert-success ng-hide"><strong>Welcome!</strong> Content is loading, please hold.</div>',
    link: function(scope, element) {...
```

**Does not work:**

```
app.directive('resolveLoader', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'loadingView.html',
        link: function(scope, element) {...
```

Please see the modified Plunker below (which does not work properly):

http://plnkr.co/edit/cpLDciUsXvIBL6fzAzWj?p=preview

Comment: @slashhp Can you elaborate what is not working and how ur controlling ng-hide in loadingView.html file ..I removed it then able to see the template

Comment: why are you using `ng-hide` as class and not using it as attribute directive with a value? That is not how you normally use it

Comment: swapnesh & charlietfl, this was not originally my code, but rather the solution posted by tasseKATT--I was simply curious about why exactly his solution worked with "template" instead of "templateUrl."  After reviewing the comment on the original answer pointed out by Floyd Pink, it appears this is a timing issue with the link function.  Thanks for your input, though!

Comment: Shouldn't templateUrl: in the first resolveLoader directive be template: instead?

Comment: @zszep, you're right--I've fixed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment on the original answer, it is a timing issue and you would not need the `$timeout` when `templateUrl` is used.

So this:

```
link: function(scope, element) {

  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, currentRoute, previousRoute) {
    if (previousRoute) return;

    $timeout(function() {
      element.removeClass('ng-hide');
    });
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    element.addClass('ng-hide');
  });
}
```

will change to:

```
link: function(scope, element) {

  element.removeClass('ng-hide');

  var unregister = $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    element.addClass('ng-hide');
    unregister();
  });
}
```

Here is the plunk with the fixed solution for using `templateUrl` (from the original answer's comment): http://plnkr.co/edit/31qu9xcZCCEzSfHn5YyN?p=preview

Comment: I completely missed that comment but now I understand that it is in fact a timing issue.  Thank you for pointing this out, as your solution has the code now working properly!!

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comment, you have to replace templateUrl with template in the first directive and then it works like this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rkQxLDrgqGMbRXaEkZYO?p=preview):

```
    app.directive('resolveLoader', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        // wrong
        //templateUrl: '<div class="alert alert-success ng-hide">
        // should be
        template: '<div class="alert alert-success ng-hide"><strong>Welcome!</strong> Content is loading, please hold.</div>',
        link: function(scope, element) {...
```

And then there is no timing issue, at least in my chrome browser.