# UI-Router rootscope onchange event with $scope parameter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I want to use the fromState $scope in a function which is called in an
unnamed function at the rootscope event.

It looks like that right now:

```
$rootscope.$on('$stateChangeStart'
   function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        somethingService.saveSomething($scope)//the scope from fromState
   }
)
```

So i explain my whole model:
somethingService is a service with all my DB functions for something.
saveSomething is a method which saves something to the DB.

The fromState is the state I am currently working on something.
When I change the state it should save the $scope.something by calling somethingService.saveSomething($scope.something) automatically with an event.

Here is the Documentation for the Statechange event which only exist at $rootscope level [DOC](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)

Comment: can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Ill put some more ressources in a sec

Comment: Ok thanks that would much better

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41281870/3759308) answer. $stateChange* now deprecated